# How to commit a DB transaction in Java to multiple DBs via a middle tier

Tags: java, database, transactions, high-availability

I have this scenario:

3 databases that need to be kept identical

3 java app servers that handle requests and write to the databases

each java app server connects to a single database, as well as the other app servers.

I am looking for a solution where I can have a transaction that either commits or rollsback on all 3 databases, however it seems like all the solutions I find are for a single app server connecting to all 3 databases. Normally I would implement some RPC logic such that the fact that the database is behind a second app server is transparent, however I would like to ask the following:

1. Is there a better way of doing this instead? (I don't see as having each app server connect to all the databases as a better solution, simply due to the sheer number of increased connections)
2. If not, what object should I pass with the RPC call? a Connection? a ConnectionFactory?

More context:
This is intended to be a HA solution where if a single app server or DB goes down, transactions can still occur on the remaining 2 nodes, and when the failed node comes back up, it will re-sync and then come back "online". Each app server/DB pair is in a seperate datacenter, and the cross-datacenter connections should be kept to a minimum. The writes are inevitably going to be cross-datacenter, in order to keep the DB's in sync, however the reads (main usecase) don't need to be, as if an app server is "online", then it can be fairly confident that it's data is an identical copy to the other's. I haven't found a good way to do this in the DB layer, as MMR seems to be a very restrictive PITA. Also, any solution should be scalable such that if the node count increases to 4/5/6/etc. any changes are limited to configuration, and not code changes as much as possible.

Comment: Distributed transactions are extremely complicated and as such most tools avoid supporting them.  You need to have a phase where a transaction is almost committed but not finally committed and most database don't support this. i.e. you need to be able to do a "tentative-commit" which can fail and a "final-commit" which cannot fail.  It's the cannot fail part which is tricky because you might fail. ;)

Comment: Most cross-data center solutions use eventual consistency.  This is because the chance of solution going wrong is fairly high and eventual consistency is more fault tolerant. e.g. say your database goes down, it might allow changes the other database don't and visa-versa.  This would prevent any more changes until all databases are in sync.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for the comments, I will look into the eventual consistency since that is good enough for me (I can put the requests on some messaging queue), but I still need to get that "final-commit" that cannot fail in at some point, any ideas on how to implement it in java? (or any other solutions that can implement such a thing?)

Comment: To add to what Peter Lawrey has said, your requirements that the databases (1) be identical, and (2) will be highly available violate the [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_theorem). You can have #1 or #2, not both.

Comment: @kdgregory I don't feel like I am asking the impossible.. I just need a system that can handle 1/3 nodes failing - basically the same thing the a raid5 array does (or a SAN), but with databases instead of disks - the CAP scenario is that where two disconnected systems recieve conflicting requests, however in my scenario the solution for that is simple: the request is ignored/refused unless the system recieving it is connected to the "majority" (which means that in my case, if 2/3 nodes are down, then the entire system is down).

Comment: OK, so you're going to verify that you're connected to the "majority" or reject the request. Will you do this at the start of the request or the end? Can you guarantee that you're still part of the "majority" at the time you notify the others? What happens if your message goes out, reaches some of the others, and then you discover that you're not part of the "majority"? This is *not* a simple problem, and if you go into it with the mindset that it is simple, you're going to create a buggy implementation.

Comment: That said, you could probably make this work by sending all updates to a durable message topic, and perform actual database updates by reading this topic. This limits your exposure to a single write operation, and the request will succeed/fail only if this write succeeds. This is, however, *eventual* consistency, and weights the "A" part of CAP over "C".

Comment: @kdgregory - Thanks for the concern, I was thinking more along the lines of the following: request comes in to sv1, sv1 sends request to sv2 and sv3, and then checks that the majority responded with an "OK I got the message and it's valid" - if sv1 does not recieve the ack, then it will re-calculate if it's still part of the majority or not - then once the majority has it in it's "pending" queue, it will make the decision to execute the sql, and then do another check-in to verify that the majority has done the check-in. Once the majority has done the check-in, then they will all commit.

Comment: And in the event of an error after the "majority commit" decision, then the individual sv would be responsible for eventually updating its DB (and could also provide the "good" data to any incomming requests as well) - the durable messages could also work, but I am not sure if there is much benefit (or am I just missing it)?

Comment: Receiving an ack, does not mean that the database will be able to commit the local transaction to disk. How will this situation be rectified (compensated transactions?) It sounds like providing some form of distributed txn without involvement of the database (database thinks this is a local transaction). This requires through testing of the error cases and will most probably never work correctly (think: what happens if sv1 dies and depending when)